# Can New Caledonian crows survive on their own in Europe?

Tags: ornithology

Is it possible to insert [New Caledonian crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Caledonian_crow) in Europe and have them survive on their own, mate, lay egg, hatch and so on?

The motive for the question is to find cheap labor, highly capable animals similar to working dogs, since the New Caledonian crow is among the ablest land animals known.

Comment: This question could be improved by adding in your own research on what introduced bird species are present in Europe.

Comment: This question is potentially about invasive species introduction. The motives for the question would be welcome. That species has lived in temperatures always warmer than 15 degrees for many generations and would have some disadvantages, compared to european crows. Yes they can breed a bit, but there is no scientific information to say if they would proliferate.

Comment: What kind of work would a New Caledonian crow do?  They're pretty small, couldn't herd sheep or carry anything big.  I suppose they could act as rather unusual service animals - they wouldn't take up much space!  Also, there seems to be a fair bit of research that shows that some of the native crow species in Europe are capable of doing some very clever things - the gap might not be all that big, it might just be that the New Caledonian crows were studied earlier.